# Undefined method `spree_api_key=' (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, spree

I have a rails app that I have been working on for sometime now.  I recently found out about the `Solidus` gem and and decided to bundle it in my app.  I followed the instructions from [here](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus), to get the gem up running. And everything worked like a charm except when creating an `Admin` user I run into the following error,

`Undefined method`spree_api_key=' (NoMethodError)`

I stumbled across [this](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/issues/681), earlier today, where a member discusses the same issue that I am having, so I followed his advice, and removed the `devise` gem from my app, then reinstalled `Solidus` but I am still getting the above mentioned error, when trying to edit an admin user.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.